# f# query expression to get elements by Id on a list

Tags: f#

I'm using f# to update a DB from a csv file, so I'm using `Fsharp.Data` to parse it, and it works well, as intended, and then `SqlProvider` to do the actual update.
So I get a `list` of items from my csv and one of the fields is an identifier for the table I'm meaning to update. I come from a c# background so using `LINQ` I sould do something like this:

```
var results = context.MyTable.Where(m => myList.Contains(m.Identifier))
```

and that would give me the rows I'm looking for. I tried to do this

```
query {
    for m in ctx.Dbo.MyTable do
    where (List.contains m.Identifier myList)
    select m
}
```

and got this error at runtime:

> System.InvalidOperationException: variable 'm' of type 'FSharp.Data.Sql.Common.SqlEntity' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
>      at Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.EvaluateQuotation(FSharpExpr e)
>      at Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.EvalNonNestedInner(CanEliminate canElim, FSharpExpr queryProducingSequence)
>      at Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.clo@1727-1.Microsoft-FSharp-Linq-ForwardDeclarations-IQueryMethods-Execute[a,b](FSharpExpr`1 q)
>      at .$FSI_0006.main@()
>   Stopped due to error

then tried the following

```
query {
    for m in ctx.Dbo.MyTable do
    for id in myList do
    where (id = m.Identifier)
    select m
}
```

and got this at compile time:

> myScript.fsx(291,30): error FS0001: The type 'string list' is not compatible with the type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

I'm sure this can be done, I'd like to know what am I doing wrong

What is the right way to go about this?
What is it that I'm assuming that is evidently wrong?

### Update

I just followed Aaron answer, this is how my code looks now, the relevant part at least:

```
let ctx = Sql.GetDataContext();

let getZipCodes (zipcodes: string list) = 
    query {
        for zc in ctx.CleanZipCodes do
        for id in zipcodes do
        where (id = zc.ZipCode)
        select zc
    }
    |> Seq.toList
```

and now I get this error:

> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. --->
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action'1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource'1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>      at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'1.GetResults(Nullable'1 forMergeOption)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>      at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToList[T](IEnumerable'1 source)
>      at .$FSI_0006.main@()

Comment: The runtime doesn't know how to translate `List.contains` into SQL. You need to use the LINQ's extension method `.Contains`

Comment: The second example works for me with `SqlEntityConnection`, but not with `SqlDataConnection`.  Which one are you using?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I understand what you're saying I just don't know how to use it, could you please guide me or point me somewhere I can see it at work? Thanks

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach I'm using the `SqlProvider` package with the `SqlDataProvider` as the context provider. How should I use the one you're using? Thanks

Comment: Regarding the latest edit, how big is your local list of zip codes?  Does it work with a list of one or two zip codes?

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach it works for 2 ZipCodes though I have 100+ right now and I could probably have larger sets in the future. Any ideas? And thank you so much

Comment: It looks like LINQ creates a `SELECT` sub-query for each element in the list, does a `UNION ALL` of each `SELECT` query, and then does an `INNER JOIN` between the database table and the result of the `UNION ALL`s.  There is probably a limit to the number of nested unions that can be in a SQL query.  Given that you have a large list, you may want to dynamically build an `IN` clause instead of using a LINQ query.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach you mean generate the sql script and run it from f#? I was hoping for something more Linq like as done in c#. Guess the sql literal will do for now then ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yes, I meant something like `String.Join(", ", myList |> List.map sprintf "'%s'")` (or the parameterized equivalent).

Comment: I know, I was just hoping for something along the lines of `Where(z => myList.Contains(z.ZipCodes))` as done in c# LINQ which generates the `in` automagically. I'll take a look at my choices to run the SQL literal. Thanks for the pointers 

Answer (score 2):

The error in your second example seems to be an issue with LINQ to SQL.  You can work around it by using the SQL Entity type provider, which is called `SqlEntityConnection` in the built-in type providers:

```
#r "System.Data.Entity"
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders"

open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

type SqlDb = SqlEntityConnection<"...">

let context = SqlDb.GetDataContext()

let myList = [...]

query {
    for record in context.MyTable do
    for id in myList do
    where (id = record.Identifier)
    select record
} |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: sorry for the lateness I just tried this and got this error `error FS0001: The type 'string list' is not compatible with the type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>'`.